# how to upload json to s3 with the help of lambda python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I want to upload the JSON file to the s3 bucket with the help of lambda. I have added pandas to the layer already. there is no issue with permissions. can also if also want to upload as csv how can I do that.

```
import pandas as pd

# import json
import json
import boto3
# store the URL in url 

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket ='aws-simplified-transactions420'
    url = 'https://house-stock-watcher-data.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/data/all_transactions.json'
    df = pd.read_json(url)
    data = df.to_json()
    fileName = 'data' + '.json '
    uploadByteStream = bytes(json.dumps(data.encode='UTF-8'))
    s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=fileName, Body=uploadByteStream)
    print('Put Complete')
```

the error message

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': keyword can't be an expression (lambda_function.py, line 16)",
  "errorType": "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\" Line 16\n        uploadByteStream = bytes(json.dumps(data.encode='UTF-8'))\n"
  ]
}
```

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
data.encode='UTF-8'
```

it should be:

```
data.encode('UTF-8')
```